# Behaviour of Hankel function $H_s^{(1)}(x)$ near $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

I am looking for a reference to the fact
$H_s^{(1)}(x) \approx i (\frac{2}{x})^s \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\pi}$
for small $x$,and $s\in \mathbb{C}$. I think it is obtained from some integral representation of $H_s^{(1)}(x)$.

**Edit:** By reference I mean a book that also explains this estimation.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked in Abramowitz and Stegun?

Comment: I know it is there but I want to understand the underlying explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Re s > 0$ you have from http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7.E7
$$H_s^{(1)}(x) \sim - H_s^{(2)}(x) \sim - \frac{i}{\pi}\Gamma(s)\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)^{-s}$$
The Abramowitz/Stegun equivalent is 9.1.9 (there $Y_s$ is considered, you have to divide by $\pm i$)